# Ошибка при подключение к локальной базе данных

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, сервер

Никак не могу настроить бд в локальной сети. Что бы не делал выдает "Ошибка подключения". Хотя к базе данных, что находится на самом компьютере подключается без проблем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В postgresql написано вот это:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
```

port = 5421             # (change requires restart)

В pg_hba написано вот это:

```txt
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
hostssl    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

```
public static Connection getDbConnection() {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка нет драйвера");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Драйвер найден");
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("База данных подключена");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ошибка");
    }
    return   connection;
}
```

Comment: Замените скриншоты на текст, очень трудно читать

Comment: И покажите что в методе getConnection()

Comment: Добавил метод getConnection()